# What should I input on a function like this?

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am a total beginner on python so I cannot interpret this code completely sorry
I have a function that looks like this

```
import requests

def auth(id,pw):
    s=requests.Session()
    s.post('https://portal.korea.ac.kr/common/Login.kpd',data={'id':id,'pw':pw})    
    r=s.post('http://portal.korea.ac.kr/front/ClassConfirm.kpd',data={'id':id, 'pw':pw})
    return r.text
```

if I want a html page returned that this function gives, how or what form should I input the id and password string after I run this function on the IDLE?
(*I already installed the requests module with pip)

Comment: Unfortunately this question is completely unclear. The function takes your id and password; where are you confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the id and passwords as string to auth function.

```
auth('your_id', 'your_pass')
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was the answer that I needed.